# Why configuring (0,0,0) as color for the video plane gives green color instead of black color

Tags: rgb

I have a video plane which needs to be configured for the background color.
I wanted to set the background to be black, so I configured the red=0, green=0 and blue=0.
But the background color turns out to be green.
Any tips on this?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** by including a [mcve]. See also [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely that your video plane is in **YUV** color space, and not **RGB** color space.

The video plane is converted from YUV to RGB color space before it is being displayed.

YUV color space is used as a synonym for [YCbCr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr) color space.
There are two mainly used standards, with slightly different conversion coefficients.

- In BT.601 standard the YUV triplet `[0, 0, 0]` translates to RGB value `[0, 136, 0]`.
- In BT.709 standard the YUV triplet `[0, 0, 0]` translates to RGB value `[0, 77, 0]`.

In both standards YUV=[0,0,0] results a **green** color in RGB color space.